# I cannot figure out how to interpret `someday' as a date or time [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, time

I am working on python with piece of about date-time.Its purpose is to list the files from specific date in the past util today. Unfortunately, I get this error:
**I cannot figure out how to interpret `someday' as a date or time**

Code:

```
import os
import datetime

day = 3
hour = day * 24
today =datetime.date.today()
someday = today - datetime.timedelta(hours=hour)

print someday, today

os.system('find . -type f -newerat someday !  -newerat today')
```

Result:

**2016-08-31 2016-09-03
find: I cannot figure out how to interpret `someday' as a date or time**

I know I am missing something to define "someday" is a date. When I put manually "2016-08-31" over "someday" it works.

Someone here can spend your treasure time to help me. I am so grateful for your help.

Thank you

Comment: Notice that the error message comes from `find`, not from Python.

Answer (score 2):

`someday` is a `datetime.date` object. Your question seems to be really about how to use it in your call to `find`. Just putting `someday` in the string doesn't work, since Python has no way to know that the `"someday"` part of the string is related to the `someday` variable.

You could use string formatting to insert `someday` and `today` into the string you're passing to `os.system`:

```
os.system('find . -type f -newerat {} ! -newerat {}'.format(someday, today))
```

A better option might be to use a more sophisticated library function, like one of the options in the `subprocess` module. They can generally take a list of parameters to pass to whatever outside program you choose.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['find', '.', '-type', 'f', '-newerat', str(someday), 
                                       '!', '-newerat', str(today)])
```

Comment: omg, thank you so much, I was thinking about this method I have read in somewhere. It works like a charm. many thanksssss

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the literal values `someday` and `today` in your `find` command string, you need to include the string representation of those python variables.  Try one of these:

```
os.system('find . -type f -newerat ' + str(someday) + ' ! -newerat ' + str(today))

os.system('find . -type f -newerat %s ! -newerat %s' % (str(someday), str(today)))
```

Comment: PS - both of these assume that the `str()` representation of dates are (a) valid input to the `find` command that (b) do not include spaces or shell special characters.

Comment: Or more reliably/correctly, use `subprocess` and pass the variables as part of a command `list`.